# InvalidXmlDocument: XML specified is not syntactically valid

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am following the following tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-move?tabs=azure-portal when I deploy the resource it says validation passed but then deployment failed with error bellow,

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidXmlDocument",
      "message": "XML specified is not syntactically valid.\nRequestId:xxxx-xxx-xxx-36f2-xxx\nTime:2021-08-23T07:41:21.5159975Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is just json file and no XML anywhere? Just export template and deploy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading a lot from,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/340510/arm-templates-storageaccountsfileservices-error-34.html
[Facing Issues on Deploying template for Azure File Share Storage Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341090/facing-issues-on-deploying-template-for-azure-file-share-storage-account)

I have removed the fileServices, queueServices and tableServices from the template.json file and it works.

Comment: In my case, the error stemmed from invalid/deprecated properties I was using based on the api version. Specifically the smb property on fileServices.

Comment: After removing the fileServices, BlobServices and queueService, it worked for me as well. I keep the TableService since that is what I am trying to create.

Comment: @Richard Yes.  Remove the pieces you are NOT using.  In our case, the problem was the the `export template` tool in the azure portal exported an ARM template containing the undesired elements.  We kept `blobServices` because that is what we want, but we had to delete `fileServices`, `queueServices`, and `tableServices` in order for our template to avoid this error

Answer (score 5):

The error is most probably caused by empty properties in the elements *fileServices*, *queueServices* and/or *tableServices* in your ARM-template.

For example:

```
"smb": {},
"cors": {
"corsRules": []
}
```

You don't have to remove the elements, just remove the properties. Sometimes you need these elements, that's why I wouldn't advice to remove them if you don't know if you need them. Most probably it is generating some XML under the hood and throws the error you get (don't know for sure though).

Example:

[Remove the properties from the template.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RIUc.png)

Comment: Removing "smb" property works for me (@SleepyTonic comment of the other response)